# How to custom multiple snippets in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I custom a snippet in VS code.And code as below:

```
"angular2-logger": {
    "prefix": "log",
    "body": [
        "this.log.log('$1');"
    ],
    "description": "使用angular2-logger的log功能"
}
```

But what if wanna add more snippets?Who can give me a demo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a comma in the end after the parentheses and create your next snippet.

For example:

```
"angular2-logger": {
    "prefix": "log",
    "body": [
        "this.log.log('$1');"
    ],
    "description": "使用angular2-logger的log功能"
},
"Console.log": {
  "prefix": "log",
  "body": [
    "console.log($1);"
  ],
  "description": "Console.log"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After ending your 1st snippet you can add a comma after the `}` and create another snippet as you did before.
For example: (snippet for c++, note the comma)

```
"#include": {
"prefix": ["#include", "basic"],
"body": [
    "#include<iostream>\r",
    "#include<conio.h>\r",
    "using namespace std;\r",
    "int main()\r",
    "{\r",
    "\r",
    "}"],
"description": "basic starting code"
},
    "cout": {
    "prefix": "count",
    "body": [
    "cout<<\"${1:entercode}\";",
    ""
],
"description": "cout"
}
```